# Link to PDF's automatically

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, download, drupal-7

I am currently developing in Drupal 7.

My client will be uploading PDFs to a folder online.  I need links to automatically populate on a content page based on what is in the folder.

So if there are 5 PDFs in the folder Drupal will automatically display 5 unique download links to the PDFs. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/uploaded_files')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
if (substr($file,0,1) == ".") continue;
if (is_dir($file)) continue;  
if (substr($file,-3,3) != "pdf") continue;
echo '<a href="';
echo $file;
echo '" target="_blank">';
echo $file;
echo '</a><br>';
}
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```